# Single Regex to match URL

Tags: c#, regex

Any ideas how I can use a single regular expression to validate a single url and also match urls in a text block?

```
var x = "http://myurl.com";
var t = "http://myurl.com ref";
var y = "some text that contains a url http://myurl.com some where";

var expression = "\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";

Regex.IsMatch(x, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // returns true;
Regex.IsMatch(t, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // returns false;

Regex.Matches(y, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // returns http://myurl.com;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace plain URLs with links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: I think this is not the same question. The OP is interested in how to use a single regex pattern for two purposes (match an url and find urls inside a text). I don't think the problem here is how a regex pattern should look like to match all real existent urls. But it is a good reference of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to escape correctly. Use `"\\b..."` instead of `"\b..."`. `IsMatch` will also be true for partial matches. You can check if the whole input is matching by doing this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(x, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success && match.Length == x.Length))
    // full match
```

With this check and the escape fix, your expression will work as it is. You also can write a helper method for it:

```
private bool FullMatch(string input, string pattern, RegexOptions options)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, options);

    return match.Success && match.Length == input.Length;
}
```

Your code will change to this:

```
var x = "http://myurl.com";
var t = "http://myurl.com ref";
var y = "some text that contains a url http://myurl.com some where";

var expression = "\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";

FullMatch(x, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // returns true;
FullMatch(t, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // returns false;

Regex.Matches(y, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // returns http://myurl.com;
```

Comment: Thats cool, do you think it is possible to invert that FullMatch is by default

Comment: What do you mean by "by default"?

Comment: In general you can force a full match by prepending a `^` and appending a `$` to the regex pattern. But as you want to use the same regex to find matches inside a string you can't do this here.

Comment: your output is the same as the OP?

Comment: Yes it is. As desired.

Answer (score 0):

i think the word boundary is getting you; it will not match for non-word characters.

try this:

```
var expression = @"(^|\s)(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]($|\s)";
```

this will bind the start of the match to the beginning of the string or space, and the end of the match to the end of the string or space.

---

more info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>   word character. After the last character in the string, if the last
>   character is a word character. Between two characters in the string,
>   where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.
>   Simply put: \b allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using
>   a regular expression in the form of \bword\b. A "word character" is a
>   character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not
>   "word characters" are "non-word characters".

Comment: The `\s` isn't escaped correctly here. But as good as your regex pattern is, `Regex.IsMatch` will return `true` for the second input as it finds a partial match. The problem isn't the regex pattern but `Regex.IsMatch` as it allows partial matches.

Comment: edited to fix the `\s` issue. why isn't true valid for the second input? "...and also match urls in a text block". looks like a "text block" to me :-?

Comment: The OP wants a regex pattern to match a string to an url. The second input `"http://myurl.com ref"` isn't a valid url, so a full match aproach should return false while a in-text-seach should return the url within. Therefore the `Regex.Matches` method should be used for checking in-text-search and a full-match-method should be used to check if a single string is an url. And `Regex.IsMatch` won't do that as it will also be `true` if the input string CONTAINS a valid url instead of IS an url.